# CCAvenue Android Integration

Tags: php, android, ccavenue

I am integrating CCAvenue to my android app and I am doing Non-seamless integration.

My merchant server is php and I am making my httppost to the GetRSA.php file kept in my merchant server.

The code I am using is as below

```
 List<NameValuePair> httpParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_code", intent.getStringExtra("access_code")));
 httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order_id", intent.getStringExtra("order_id")));

 String vResponse = sh.makeServiceCall(intent.getStringExtra(RSA_KEY_URL), ServiceHandler.POST, httpParams);
```

The access code, order id and the RSA url is passed from the previous activity and the ACESS_CODE I am using is the one provided by the CCAvenue and the RSA_KEY_URL is the path where I kept the GetRSA.php in the merchant server.

But the response I am getting is  "!ERROR!Caller IP not registered/Merchant Not found."

What can be wrong?

Comment: I am also getting the same error, did you solve it?

Comment: no luck yet.. please update if you get any info ..

Comment: i called the ccavenue customer care they gave me different access code..and it worked.
you also call them
Ancy Cardoz
Executive- Compliance
Sales Support Team          
Avenues India Pvt Ltd
Plaza Asiad, Levell 2, S V Road,
Santacruz West, Mumbai - 400054, India
Tel No. 61666000  / 67425555  Extn - 615, 548, 549, 546, 545, 547,550, 638, 639

Comment: actually the website is working with the access code , only the android app has problem. Anyways i will try calling them. Thank you so much for the info.

Comment: Yes, same here even my website was working but for mobile they gave me different access code now i have 2 access codes.
Before making the app live we need to call them again and ask as which access code to use as they register the "Caller IP" on their side.
add me on facebook as we might need each others help in ccavenue
my email id is dpkramrakhyani@gmail.com

Comment: Hi, I could contact them over chat and they did some changes at their side and now it is working for me. I am using the same access code as the website. Even my webview page entries were disabled. That too they could correct it .

Answer (score 0):

It is because at ccavenue there are server to server call, so they get a hit from our server's outgoing Static IP..
As they have validations at their end..you get  "!ERROR!Caller IP not registered/Merchant Not found."

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure that your Public/Outgoing IP has been whitelisted on CCAvenue's end.Also Make sure you are using the proper Access Code,Merchant ID and working key provided by CCAvenue.See the Link

> [CCAvenue Integration in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794840/ccavenue-integration-in-android?rq=1)