# CCAvenue Integration in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, payment-gateway, ccavenue

Nice to meet you.

I am developing shopping app using parse.com as backend.
I am going to integrate with Indian Payment Gateway(CCAVenue).
I am integrating CCAvenue to my android app and I am doing Non-seamless integration.
My merchant server is php and I am making my httppost to the GetRSA.php file kept in my merchant server.
The code I am using is as below

```
 List<NameValuePair> httpParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_code", intent.getStringExtra("access_code")));
 httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order_id", intent.getStringExtra("order_id")));

 String vResponse = sh.makeServiceCall(intent.getStringExtra(RSA_KEY_URL), ServiceHandler.POST, httpParams);
```

The access code, order id and the RSA url is passed from the previous activity and the ACESS_CODE I am using is the one provided by the CCAvenue and the RSA_KEY_URL is the path where I kept the GetRSA.php in the merchant server.

But the response I am getting is "!ERROR!Caller IP not registered/Merchant Not found."

What can be wrong?

I will wait your reply.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any reason why payment related queries are being negative ranked in stackoverflow.

Comment: hey can you provide me the code for ccavenue pg integration?

Answer (score 19):

This error will come because your server requests are block listed by avenues server.
First you have to white list your merchant server out going ip address with ccavenue server.
follow below steps to do the same.

ping your merchant server url from command prompt, to get out going ip address. Or optionally ask your merchant server hosting team customer support to get your out going ip for your merchant server.

send a mail to salessupport@ccavenue.com, saying white list that out going ip. To get immediate reply to your mail, after send mail to avenues team call them immediately.

for more details call avenues customer technical support team at +91 22 67425555 
and press 2 to reach technical team.

They will solve your issue in minutes, don't waste time in stack overflow. You will get very less support in stack overflow esp related to payment gateways, better you depend on technical support team.

Happy integration.

Answer (score 0):

IP address confilcts there ...request is going from another ip address(outgoing server ip address i.e  where you have hosted the payment integration files).and you have given another ip address to  ccavenue.

Comment: The user is point out that he got an ""!ERROR!Caller IP not registered/Merchant Not found." error. So he wants to know why. It is obvious that it IP doesn't much with the CCAVenue IP List. But why? Please check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Comment: B'cause CCAVENUE has to add the outgoing server ip address to there gatway server (i.e. from the location request is coming) so that they can identify that the request is coming from trusted server/location (i.e registerd ip-- which is given by you)
shareeditdeleteflag

Answer (score 0):

You have to do mail to service@ccavenue.com this mail id with your server ip and merchant id for whitelist your outgoing IP address to avoid the below error .

```
!ERROR!Caller IP not registered/Merchant Not found.
```